# Rotate clock's hour hand along with minute hand

Tags: ios, ios7, core-animation

I am using CALayers to make an analog clock. The real-time clock works perfect and all the hands are moving smoothly just like default clock app icon in iOS. However, when I try to move the clock hands by touch/dragging, the minute hand moves perfectly but the hour hand doesn't. I am trying to move the clock hands just as they move in a real gear-based clock. Any solutions on how to calculate the angle for hour hand with respect to the movement of minute hand both clockwise and counter-clockwise? Actually I want somewhat similar functionality to this app https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/bb-teaching-clock/id612261763?mt=8

Here is the code for minute hand rotation

```
    float dx = touchPoint.x - minHand.position.x;
    float dy = touchPoint.y - minHand.position.y;

    deltaAngle = atan2f(dy,dx);
    startTransform = minHand.transform;
    float angleDifference;

    float dx = pt.x  - minHand.position.x;
    float dy = pt.y  - minHand.position.y;
    float ang = atan2f(dy,dx);

angleDifference = deltaAngle - ang;

    minHand.transform = CATransform3DRotate(startTransform, -angleDifference,0 ,0 ,1);
    NSLog(@"angleDifference: %f", angleDifference);

   CGFloat hourAngle = (1/12)*(angleDifference);
// hour hand should move in the same direction as minute hand but at a much slower rate
hourHand.transform = CATransform3DRotate (hourHand.transform, -hourAngle, 0, 0, 1);
```

Comment: For every degree the minute hand moves, the hour hand moves 1/12*degree

Comment: This has to be in degree or radians?

Comment: I tried it with both degrees and radians but nothing happened. I have edited my post to add code for rotation of both hands.

Comment: You don't need the Degrees2Radians() call since angleDifference is already in radians

Comment: The hour hand does not move :(

Comment: Did you remove the Degrees2Radians? And shouldn't hourAngle be -hourAngle in CATransform3DRotate?

Comment: Yes but no effect on the hour hand. hourAngle is -hourAngle. I have edited my post.

Comment: What is the value of hourAngle when you change the minute hand by 30 minutes?

Comment: It's not moving. So, it is always 0.00000

Answer (score 0):

Try making the following changes, where centerPoint is the center of the clock...

```
float dx = touchPoint.x - centerPoint.x;
float dy = touchPoint.y - centerPoint.y;
deltaAngle = atan2f(dy,dx);

startTransform = minHand.transform;
float angleDifference;

dx = minHand.position.x - centerPoint.x;
dy = minHand.position.y - centerPoint.y;
float ang = atan2f(dy,dx);

angleDifference = ang - deltaAngle;
```

Comment: Already tried this. It moves the hour hand three times faster than the minute hand

Comment: How is that possible when you are dividing the angle by 12?

Comment: Hour hand has slowed down a bit but still it is faster than the minute hand. It is also showing some weird behavior now. It moves to and fro once and then a full rotationhourAngle: 0.057954
hourAngle: 0.050208
hourAngle: 0.041309
hourAngle: 0.029762
hourAngle: 0.020621

Comment: If you move the minute hand by 15 minutes, what is the value of hourAngle?

Comment: It should be ~0.13089 and angleDifference should be 1.57079 (pi/2).

Comment: I modified my answer.

Comment: it solved the hour hand problem but messed up the minHand rotation :(

Comment: I made a minor change to my answer. Try it now.

Comment: minHand is vibrating and rotating.